# Image is not loading in view after selection from library with xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to simply select an image from the iphone’s library and display it on the view.  Here is the header file reference:

```
@interface myappViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
UIImagePickerController *imagepicker;
UIImagePickerController *imagepicker2;
UIImage *image;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imagepickerview;

}

- (IBAction)TakePhoto;
- (IBAction)ChooseExisting;

@end
```

Here is the implementation code:

```
@interface myappViewController ()

@end

@implementation myappViewController

- (IBAction)TakePhoto{

imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagepicker.delegate = self;
[imagepicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)ChooseExisting{

imagepicker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagepicker2.delegate = self;
[imagepicker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:imagepicker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagepicker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imagepickerview setImage:image];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)imagepickerview{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

On the storyboard I have two buttons.  One for choose existing and one for take photo.  If I select the choose existing the library opens and I can select an image.  The problem is that the image is not selected and then redirected back to the xcode view.  Rather, I have to click the cancel button in the navigation controller of the photo library and then I see the image loaded in the view.  Any idea why this is not properly loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `valueForKey` instead of `objectForKey` also dismiss the image picker before getting the image.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imagepickerview setImage:image];
```

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed it.  I do get two warnings though.  `1) dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated` and `2) Local declaration of imagepicker hides instance variable` what is my best fix to clear these out?

Comment: use "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];" to remove the all the warnings.answer updated.